syntactic negation and falsehood
Delong (A profile of Mathematical Logic §16 p. 170 in the Kindle edition) wrote that we can denying the antecedent by having an obviously false consequence follow from it.

A similar device is sometimes used in mathematical logic by allowing ‘ƒ’ to stand for some standard false sentence.

I encountered this in Quine (Completeness of the Propositional Calculus) in the name of Tarski, Bernays and Wahlberg.
DeLong explained that this ‘ƒ’ stand some standard false sentence.
In §19, introducing the Metatheory, he wrote

The general idea of consistency is that a statement (or system of statements) is consistent if it is possible for it to be true. This is sometimes called a semantical definition of consistency, since it makes reference to truth. Semantics, as we shall understand the term, is a study of interpretations of languages, including formal languages.

Further,

We can now present a syntactical definition of consistency: A formal system is consistent if there is no formula such that both it and its negation are theorems. Of course, the negation might be represented in different ways in different systems.... in another ‘A ⊃ f’

To call a sentence false is a semantic calling. So, it seems as we have entered the semantical truth into Object Language. And it's further used for Syntax.
I would tend to think that the introduction of Falsehood into Object Language is a theoretical error, but the great logicians whose names I have cited do it. Can you explain to me how Falsehood enters Syntax through the Object Language in the form of Denial?

A "semantic calling" is to call a sentence false in some interpretation. The "standard false sentence" is a purely syntactic concept, that of contradiction, and the use of "false" is purely nominal (it happens to be false in any interpretation). It is now often denoted ⊥ (instead of f) and called falsum. One can introduce ⊥ syntactically as p ∧ ¬p, where p is any sentence, if one has negation in the syntax. And conversely, one can introduce negation ¬p syntactically as p → ⊥ if one has ⊥ in the syntax.

You may be stumbling over the fact that consistency can be defined as a syntactic property of a theory ("no contradiction can be derived" -- but that definition itself uses the not-purely-syntactic property of "derivability in T" or of "being a theorem of T") but it can also be defined as a semantic property ("there is a truth assignment to T" -- which presupposes syntactic consistency - since there is no truth assignment to any p and ¬p that makes both true).

Note that negation/falsum are not strictly necessary if you can represent a falsehood at the level of whatever first-order theory you’re in, e.g. 0=1 in PA.

@Conifold I appreciate your comment and now have to learn it slowly. I corrected and error in the question. The falsum is in Object Language primarily.

To expand @PW_246's comment: "0=1" is an example of a standard false sentence in PA. FOL with equality has other examples like "∃x: x≠x". (To those who smugly ask about logics without equality: feel free to work it out for yourself; your standard false sentences will be the initial objects in the term model of your logic. If there are no initial objects in the model, then there are no absolute falsehoods in the theory.)

We introduce the falsum propositional constant whose intended meaning is "absurdity" or "contradiction".
From a syntactical point of view, it will be managed by rules.
Obviously, there is no Introduction rule for it: we want that the calculus is consistent, but there is a Elimination rule, the Ex Falso (aka: Explosion) rule:

(⊥E) ⊥⊢φ

that reads: "from a contradiction we can derive a proposition whatever".
With it, we may define negation of a proposition A in the usual way as A → ⊥.
Alternatively, having the negation sign ¬ as primitive, with his pair of I- and E-rule, we define ⊥ as contradiction whatever.
But see Neil Tennant, Negation, Absurdity and Contrariety for a discussion of the "received view" above summarized.
Syntax is defined independently from semantics but, obviously, the "rules of the game" are defined with some natural expectations in mind: conjuntion formalizes "and" etc.
But see Proof-Theoretic Semantics for the view that meaning of connectives is determined by their rules: proof is fundamental rather than truth.

Thanks so much for your rich answer.  Btw I corrected an error in the formulation of the question. '→F ' belongs to the Object Language.   You writes that reads: "from a contradiction we can derive a proposition whatever". Contradiction is not an intrusion of the Syntax in the Object Language?

@kouty not clear... The object language is exactly the formal language whose syntax we are discussing.

The concept of contradiction is a judgement about two propositions of the object language. Maybe I wrongly understand you. You wrote that the falsum intended meaning is contradiction. The falsum belongs to the Object Language. Can we read the Object Language saying ( ~A) ←→ (A → contradiction) ?

@kouty yes, syntactically a sime contradiction is A and not-A.


I would tend to think that the introduction of Falsehood into Syntax is a theoretical error, but the great logicians whose names I have cited do it. Can you explain to me how Falsehood enters Syntax in the form of Denial?

I can explain why seemingly great logicians support an obviously false theory: Expediency.
They have worked for a long time and couldn't find a better alternative. So, in desperation, they fell back on the one they had.
There is probably a psychological bias to boot. Often, people deny the reality of a problem because they have no idea how to remove the problem.
It should also be noticed that the theory in question is a mathematical theory, not a scientific one. The mentality is different. In science, you want your theory to be true of the real world. False theories are expected to be eventually falsified, so any self-respecting scientific certainly doesn't want to work on a false theory if this is avoidable. On the other hand, in mathematics, you do as you please, at least as long as your theory appears self-consistent. There is no effort to prove that a mathematical theory is false of the real world.

Which tautology of Classical Logic is false in the real world, and what do you mean by ‘false’?

@PW_246 "Which tautology of Classical Logic is false in the real world" I already gave you a number of examples. What is false are not the tautologies, but the theory which says that they are true. - 2. "and what do you mean by ‘false’?" I speak English. I don't speak mathematics.

if the theory is false, then at least one of its principles or theorems must not be true in general. Which tautology can be made false, and in which sense?
